# How to report agent variables in a consistent order in Netlogo's Behaviourspace

Tags: netlogo, behaviorspace

[Picture of my behaviourspace menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8mBY.jpg)

I'm working on an agent based model where a variable (agentvariable1) owned by all agents changes every tick. I want to report a time series for the values of this variable for every agent using Behaviourspace.

However, when I measure runs using the following reporter

```
[agentvariable1] of turtles
```

the values that are reported for agentvariable1 are randomly shuffled, because "turtles" calls all turtles in a random order, which is different every tick. Because of this the data that is exported is not usable to create a time-series.

Is it posstible to create a reporter in Behaviourspace that reports the values of the agentvariable1 in a sequence that remains the same every tick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sort` on an agentset creates a list of those agents sorting them by some criteria. In the case of turtles, they are sorted by their `who` which means that their relative order will always be the same.

However you cannot directly do `[agentvariable1] of sort turtles`, because `of` expects an agent/agentset but you are giving it a list.

What you can do is creating a global variable as a list: at each tick the list is emptied, and later all turtles (sorted as per `sort`) will append their value to the list.
That list is what you will report in your Behavior Space.

```
globals [
  all-values
]

turtles-own [
  my-value
]

to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
  create-turtles 5
end

to go
  set all-values (list)
  
  ask turtles [
    set my-value random 10
  ]
  
  foreach sort turtles [
    t ->
    ask t [
      set all-values lput my-value all-values
    ]
  ]
  
  show all-values
  
  tick
end
```

Comment: I suspect this could be accomplished less elaborately with `map`, e.g. `map [?t -> [my-value] of ?t] sort turtles`, that kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Matteo's answer (which is perfectly suitable and directly addresses your intention, I just present another option depending on preference) you could also pair the variable of interest with some `turtle` identifier and report that as a list of lists. This adds a bit of flexibility in cases where the number of turtles increases or decreases. In this example, I use `who` and `xcor` for simplicity, but you may want to create your own unique `turtle` identifier for more explicit tracking. With this toy model:

```
to setup
  ca
  crt 5
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask turtles [
    rt random 30 - 15 
    fd 1
  ]
  tick
end

to-report report-who-x
  report list who xcor
end
```

At any point, you can call the list with `[report-who-x] of turtles` to get a list of lists. With a `behaviorspace` setup such as:

[image]

you get an output that would look something like:

[image]